# Force check-out/check-in on individual file in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, check-out

In SharePoint Online/Office 356, I want to force check-out/check-in for an individual file without applying this setting to the entire folder/library.

Is there a way to do it?

The reason for this is that I have a single file in which I want to encourage the use of check-in comments. Of course, people could still do a check-out/check in without it being required, but people simply won't do it without some "help" of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is NO.

Check in/Check out is set at library level, we can not force check-out/check-in for an individual file without applying this setting to the entire folder/library.

If you still want to do this, we suggest you create a new library for all files that need to be checked in/checked out.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to work in code, say via metadata on the file, my thinking is you could code it into a Remote Event Receiver.